# Next.js Material UI Textfield in MenuItem error

Tags: next.js, material-ui

It uses Next.js and MUI.

I am trying to use the MUI TextField select option, but when I click TextField, the following error continues to appear.

I got a code that was working somewhere else, but I don't know if it's a setup problem or not.

I'm also using styled-system, but will it conflict with each other?

I don't know which part to fix. Help me.

```
import { TextField } from "@mui/material";
// MenuItem을 불러올 때 위와 같이 수정하면 됩니다.

import MenuItem from "@mui/material/MenuItem";

import * as React from "react";
import StyledBox from "../StyledSystem/StyledBox";
import StyledSpan from "../StyledSystem/StyledSpan";

import ErrorText from "../common/ErrorText";

interface IBasicProps {}

const Basic: React.FunctionComponent<IBasicProps> = (props) => {
  return (
    <StyledBox py={30} px={40}>
      <StyledBox display='flex' flexDirection='column' fontSize={18}>
        <StyledSpan mb='2px'>
          <StyledSpan>채용 공고명</StyledSpan>
          <StyledSpan ml='3px' fontSize={13} lineHeight={1.46}>
            (50자 이내)
          </StyledSpan>
          <StyledSpan ml='3px' color='rgb(229, 0, 0)'>
        *
          </StyledSpan>
        </StyledSpan>
        <TextField placeholder='예) 000헤어 디자이너, 000네일 디자이너' />
        <ErrorText content='ERROR ERROR ERROR ERROR' />
      </StyledBox>
      <StyledBox
        display='flex'
        flexDirection='column'
        fontSize={18}
        width='100%'
      >
        <StyledSpan mb='2px'>
          <StyledSpan>직군</StyledSpan>
          <StyledSpan ml='3px' color='rgb(229, 0, 0)'>
            *
          </StyledSpan>
        </StyledSpan>
        <StyledBox width='50%'>
          <TextField
            placeholder='예) 000헤어 디자이너, 000네일 디자이너'
            fullWidth
            select
            label='직군'
          >
            <MenuItem></MenuItem>
            <MenuItem></MenuItem>
            <MenuItem></MenuItem>
            <MenuItem></MenuItem>
          </TextField>

          <ErrorText content='ERROR ERROR ERROR ERROR' />
        </StyledBox>
      </StyledBox>
    </StyledBox>
  );
};

export default Basic;
```

theme.ts

```
import { createTheme } from "@mui/material/styles";
import { red } from "@mui/material/colors";

// Create a theme instance.
const theme = createTheme({
  components: {
    // Name of the component
    MuiButtonBase: {
      defaultProps: {
        // The props to change the default for.
        disableRipple: true, // No more ripple, on the whole application !
      },
    },
  },
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: "#556cd6",
    },
    secondary: {
      main: "#19857b",
    },
    error: {
      main: red.A400,
    },
  },
});

export default theme;
```

error

[image: error]

Answer (score 0):

MenuItem takes an `onClick` handler, which it calls when it detects a click on itself or it's children.

The fact that your error is `undefined` is not a function indicates that somewhere there is code that is calling a passed in parameter *expecting* it to be a function, and in reality nothing was passed in.

I see that in your code example, you have a number of `MenuItem` elements with no onClick callbacks:

```
<MenuItem></MenuItem>
```

Which suggests to me that there is the root of your problem. I'd try adding a callback, even a noop like `() => {}` and see if it fixes the problem.